# How do I change the font or font size of the entire app in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a settings page. What we support here is font change and font size change.

I would like to get the relevant material.

I think you should use a global variable to change the font.

If so, do I need to use a global variable to change the font size?

Give me a hint!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can set it as a global variable and pass it into the `textTheme` parameter of the `ThemeData` widget of your app. (You can save it to SharedPreferences so it won't be lost after app closure and retrieve it at startup)

Answer (score 0):

Use theme widget and it will apply the customization of the theme in only child widget here you can write your custom theme for all child pages

```dart
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final AppBar appBar;

  CustomAppBar() : appBar = new AppBar();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Theme(
        child: appBar,
        data: new ThemeData(
            //write your code for font here
            ));
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => appBar.preferredSize;
}
```